# How to use a vector as argument of a function with multiple parameters in r

Tags: r, function, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I have a function with four parameters, three of which are taken from a given dataframe. I want to be able to use the function with a given dataframe using a vector of numbers as argument for the fourth parameter.
I know how to do with one value at a time, but i am sure there is a straightfoward way to do it, maybe using `for` loop

Here is an example in which a and b are variables from df dataframe, c is the number of rows in df, and d is a vector of, lets say, integer numbers from 1 to 3 :

```
set.seed(42)    
a<-runif(100,1,100)    
b<-runif(100,1,100)    
df<-data.frame(a,b)    

fun1 <- function (a, b, c, d) {    
z <- sum (( a - d ) * b / c )    
return(z)    
}
```

If i run it one value at a time:

```
fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), 1)    
fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), 2)    
fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), 3)    


> fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), 1)    
>[1] 2696.223    
> fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), 2)    
>[1] 2643.748    
> fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), 3)    
>[1] 2591.273
```

What i want to do is something like this (it should return all the three values at once):

```
fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), c(1:3))
```

Hope i was clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sapply(1:3, fun1, a = df$a, b = df$b, c = nrow(df))`

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sapply()` inside your function

```
fun1 <- function (a, b, c, d) {    
  sapply(d, function(x) { sum (( a - x ) * b / c ) })
} 

fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), c(1:3)) 
# [1] 2696.223 2643.748 2591.273
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "map" command from the purrr package. You can install purrr from command using `install.packages("purrr")`

It would look something like this:

```
# load purr library
library(purrr)

# Map your function
map(c(1:3), function(x) {fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), x)})
```

The output is a list:

```
> map(c(1:3), function(x) {fun1(df$a, df$b, nrow(df), x)})
[[1]]
[1] 2696.223

[[2]]
[1] 2643.748

[[3]]
[1] 2591.273
```